# Upgrading my for loop to c++11 style

Tags: c++11, for-loop

Is it possible to upgrade this `for` loop?

```
hItem = m_treeHistory.InsertItem(TVIF_TEXT|TVIF_PARAM,
            strText, 0, 0, 0, 0, (LPARAM)psAssign, TVI_ROOT, TVI_LAST);
if (psAssign->aryPtrAssignments.GetSize() > 0)
{
    iSize = psAssign->aryPtrAssignments.GetSize();
    for (i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
    {
        psAssignHist = (HIST_DATA_ASSIGN_S *)psAssign->aryPtrAssignments[i];
        if (psAssign != nullptr)
        {
            strText = psAssignHist->datAssignment.Format(VAR_DATEVALUEONLY);
            if (psAssignHist->strMethod != _T(""))
            {
                strText += _T(" - ");
                strText += psAssignHist->strMethod;
            }
            if (psAssignHist->strTheme != _T(""))
            {
                strText += _T(" - ");
                strText += psAssignHist->strTheme;
            }

            // AJT v10.7.0
            if (strFilterText == _T("") || IsFilteredMatch(psAssignHist))
            {
                m_treeHistory.InsertItem(TVIF_TEXT|TVIF_PARAM,
                    strText, 0, 0, 0, 0, (LPARAM)psAssignHist, hItem, TVI_LAST);
            }
        }
    }
    tvs.hParent = hItem;
    tvs.lParam = (LPARAM)&m_treeHistory;
    tvs.lpfnCompare = CompareDateAssignHistory;
    m_treeHistory.SortChildrenCB(&tvs);
}
```

It is this `for` loop:

```
iSize = psAssign->aryPtrAssignments.GetSize();
for (i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
{
```

I have looked [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/02/c-plus-plus-11/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20TheGeekStuff%20(The%20Geek%20Stuff) and it suggests:

```
for(int i: someDataStructure) doSomething();
```

But I am not sure if I can adopt this for my `psAssign->aryPtrAssignments` list which is a `CPtrArray` of `HIST_DATA_ASSIGN_S` pointers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the [ranged `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) depends on standard library iterators (i.e. `begin` and `end` functions) which doesn't exist for [`CPtrArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/99hh7dk4.aspx).

Fortunately you can create `begin` and `end` functions to handle special containers. Perhaps something like

```
void** begin(CPtrArray const& arr)
{
    return arr.GetData();
}

void** end(CPtrArray const& arr)
{
    return arr.GetData() + arr.GetSize();
}
```

<sub>Note that these should be *global non-member functions*.</sub>

Now with these helper function you should be able to use the ranged `for` loop:

```
CPtrArray myArray;

// Code to populate myArray

for (auto ptr : myArray)
{
    // Do something with the pointer ptr
}
```

Note that the `begin` and `end` functions presented here could be used for *all* standard functions that expects iterators.

Comment: How would those `begin` and `end` methods be invoked by the `for` loop?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Just like normal functions, passing the array (`myArray` in my example) as the argument. Please follow the link in my answer for a reference, which includes examples of equivalent code for the loop.

Comment: I see. So really, you are suggesting I make my own `CPtrArrayEx` class that has those methods, and then derive **my** arrays from `CPtrArrayEx` instead and I would be able to revise the way I iterate. I see. So the final logical question is, is it worth making such changes?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle No no no, make the functions *global non-member* functions. That's it. Just declare them before your loop. Updated my answer to clarify that.

Comment: Out of interest, now that I have started to use **boost** with my application, does it have any inbuilt mechanism for doing this with `CPtrArray` and `CStringArray`?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Not directly no. Much of Boost depends on other parts of Boost and of course the standard library. It really don't know anything about the Microsoft MFC classes.

Comment: Hhhm. I just found this though: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/range/doc/mfc_atl.html

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Oh, didn't know about that. :) And even though that reference you link to is *ancient* the header file is still included with the modern releases of the Boost Range library. (See e.g. [here for the latest release documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/range/doc/html/))